# Minimum Length Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will validate that user input is greater than X number of non-whitespace characters.  I'm basically trying to filter out begining and ending whitespace while still ensuring that the input is greater than X characters; the characters can be anything, just not whitespace (space, tab, return, newline).
This the regex I've been using, but it doesn't work:

```
\s.{10}.*\s
```

I'm using C# 4.0  (Asp.net Regular Expression Validator) btw if that matters.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex? You could do it without a regex pretty easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be easier to not use regex at all:

```
input.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).Count() > 10
```

If whitespace shouldn't count in the middle, then this will work:

```
(\s*(\S)\s*){10,}
```

If you don't care about whitespace in between non-whitespace characters, the other answers have that scenario covered.

Comment: Sorry, just updated.  I'm using a regular expression validator.

Comment: @Mark - should your validation fail if there is whitespace in the middle of some valid characters, e.g. `  f   a   i    l `

Comment: Nope, thats fine, just so long as there is X characters between the first non-whitespace and the last non-whitespace.

Comment: Cool thanks.  It got me on the right track, I ended up going with this: `(\b*(\S)).{10,}\b` which seems to work based on a few quick tests, but I'm obviously not a regex guru.

Comment: Even better: `(\b*(\S)\s*){10,}[\S\b]`

Comment: @Mark, `[\S\b]` (and `\b*`) is invalid/doesn't do what you think. Anyway, proper regex would be `^(?:\s*\S){10}`, will match only if there are at least 10 none-whitespate chars.

Answer (score 3):

This regular expression looks for eight or more characters between the first and last non-whitespace characters, ignoring leading and trailing whitespace:

```
\s*\S.{8,}\S\s*
```

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to check (like in my case a phone number that contains 8 digits) , you need to refer to a number below the one you need.

```
(\s*(\S)\s*){7,}
```