# textbox background color=red on validation failed?

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a `RequiredFieldValidator` and a `RegularExpressionValidator` to validate a text box field.If anyone of the validation fails, text box to have to be red.But in my case this happens on only one validator(Required field).So how to solve this issue ?

Comment: use validation summary instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can use only RegularExpressionValidator with minimum length > 0 RegEx.  This will solve your problem. For more information how to use minimum length of text please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028711/minimum-length-regular-expression) link.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="txtName" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RangeValidator"  ControlToValidate="txtName" SetFocusOnError="True" Display="Dynamic" MaximumValue="1000" MinimumValue="100" Type="Integer"></asp:RangeValidator>
```

You have to set `Display="Dynamic"` in both validator.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [link](http://alittlecode.com/jquery-form-validation-with-styles-from-twitter-bootstrap/)

Or else you achieve such functionality with twitter bootstrap

You can find it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript to do this like this :

```
function valid()
{
  return $("#<%=RequiredFiled.ClientID%>").valid() && $("#<%=RegularExpressionFiled.ClientID%>").valid()
}

if(valid())
{
  $("#<%=Error_msg%>").css("color","Red");
}
```